# NoMethodError, ActiveRecord 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to delete, not destroy (that doesn't work either), a record as a learning exercise for Rails.

In the rails console, I execute: `subject.pages.delete(second_page)` and I get the below error message (same for trying destroy).

> NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

In subject.pages is:

`=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Page id: 2, subject_id: 1, name: "First Page", permalink: "first", position: 1, visible: false, created_at: "2016-08-19 17:58:02", updated_at: "2016-08-19 17:58:02">, #<Page id: 3, subject_id: 1, name: "Second Page", permalink: "second", position: 2, visible: false, created_at: "2016-08-19 17:59:07", updated_at: "2016-08-19 17:59:07">]>`

Subject has a one to many relation with pages. Page belongs_to subject.

Ed1: It looks like 'second_page' is a local variable. So when I exited the Rails Console. I wasn't able to recreate the problem, yet I still can't delete this record.

Ed2: So, I decided to continue my learning and I didn't run into any hiccups until I used ERB calling `subject.pages.size`. Again, I got a 'NoMethodError', where the html.erb file wouldn't render. Where should I be checking to make sure I'm declaring pages correctly? I double checked the teacher's code and it all looks the same (I could be missing something minor) but I'm lost on how to fix this error in my app.

Ed3(Final): I dropped the tables created and started over. I'm not sure what the solution actually was but I do think changing the relationship in the controller did help. Thanks for helping.

Using: Rails 4.0.0, ActiveRecord 4.0.0, MySQL 5.17.14 (If more information is needed, I'll update promptly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the initial problem of deleting a record.

I wasn't able to delete this record by using `subject.pages.delete(second_page)` but I was able to delete it by using `Page.find(3).delete`.

To answer the issue regarding NoMethodError.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966519/rails-undefined-method-name-for-nilnilclass-error-when-adding-article-comm#comment57687232_34966519) comment was the most insightful to finding out this issue. Namely, since I was using Rails 4.0.0 there are issues and bugs that arise. One common issue is the NoMethodError. I upgraded to 4.1.2 by updating my Gemfile and then `bundle install` in the root directory of my app. I then restarted the Rails server and I had no issues. The subject.pages.size was able to render.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/delete) for `delete(*records)`

> For has_many associations, the deletion is done according to the strategy specified by the :dependent option.[...]
>   If no :dependent option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default strategy is :nullify. This sets the foreign keys to NULL.

That means the record is not destroyed, only the association.
You have to set the dependent option to `:destroy` to delete the record from database.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the dependent delete(destroy) option whit a has_many association, which is can't be done. This option is available only for a belongs_to association.

I hope I could have helped clear for you!

Comment: I apologize. Page does belongs_to subject. Yet I'm still having problems.